# How to write entity framework query and Linq query on c#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

[image]

Hi, I have this table.
I want to write this query in my controller.

```
select sum(Amount) from tbl_Amounts where fk_Roleid=2
```

which shows result of 800 in sql.
I don't know how to write it in both EF and Linq. If someone could kindly show me the way to write in both ways would be really helpfull.

Comment: You can use `Database.SqlQuery<TResult>` in EF to execute raw SQL queries like that. Which MVC & EF version you're using?

Comment: EF Version=4.0.0.0 and Visual studio version 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *should* basically be the Linq syntax for your request.

Linq is some "internal framework" of .NET / C#, and you use Entity framework.

There is no real meaning in separating the two, in my opinion.

This is the "Linq to SQL" syntax I would use on the "DataContext" that you cretate with EF :

```
DataContext
    .tbl_Amounts
    .Where(a => a.fk_Roleid = 2)
    .Sum(a => a.Amount);
```

If you have a collection of record called Amounts, this would be the "linq to objects" version :

```
Amounts
    .Where(a => a.fk_Roleid = 2)
    .Sum(a => a.Amount);
```

As you can see, there is no real difference ! (excepted that, under the hood, the first one on an EF Data Context will be converted to a SQL db request)

But it could actually depends on your Entity Framework version (not all linq features are correctly translated to SQL)

Comment: Thanks alot. That helped!!

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 different ways to execute SQL query in Entity Framework (EF), depending on the version you're using:

**1) Using LINQ to Entities (all versions)**

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    int amount = (from am in db.tbl_Amounts where am.fk_Roleid == 2 select am.amount).Sum();
}
```

**2) Using `Database.SqlQuery<T>()` (up to EF 6)**

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    string query = "select sum(Amount) from tbl_Amounts where fk_Roleid=2";
    int amount = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query).Single(); // or First()
}
```

**3) Using `FromSql()` (EF Core)**

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    string query = "select sum(Amount) from tbl_Amounts where fk_Roleid=2";
    int amount = db.tbl_Amounts.FromSql(query).Single(); // or First()
}
```

Note that if you're using EF Core, `Database.SqlQuery<T>` doesn't exist and you should use [Execute raw SQL query in EF Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql).

Comment: Didn't know about "`Database.SqlQuery`", interesting !(because indeed I use EFCore)

Comment: Thanks alot. That helped!!